# Check for specific characters used in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string

More specifically, i would like to know if **only** certain characters are used in a word. For example the program will detect if **only** `A` `B` and `C` are used in an input. I have this so far but obviously this is an extremely brute force method to use.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? (I should also mentions that this program doesn't work properly as I would need to add many more conditions)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = in.nextLine();

    if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O") && str.contains("S") && str.contains("H") && str.contains("Z") && str.contains("X") && str.contains("N")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O") && str.contains("S") && str.contains("H") && str.contains("Z") && str.contains("X")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O") && str.contains("S") && str.contains("H") && str.contains("Z")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O") && str.contains("S") && str.contains("H")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O") && str.contains("S")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I") && str.contains("O")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else if(str.contains("I")){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO");
    }

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this statement? `"if only certain characters are used in a word"` ? What word do you mean?

Comment: As in ONLY specified characters are used in the string. for example i would like to check if ONLY `A` `B` and `C` are used in a string. Input would be `CAB`, output would be `YES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^[ABC]+$
```

To make sure input only contains letters `A OR B OR C`

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[ABC]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
[ABC] a single character in the list (A or B or C) literally (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the `$` and `^` does? I have implemented your code and it works perfectly but what do the `^` and `$` do? As I can see from tangens' answer they are not needed?

Comment: `^` and `$` are called anchors they are used for line start and line end respectively. They aren't needed in `matches` method only as Java API implicitly assumes it is there. However for a good regex (and to to avoid matching unexpected matches) I recommend using them.

Comment: @user3315035 `^` matches the line beginning, `$` matches the line end. You don't need them because the `matches` method already checks for the entire string to match the regex

Answer (score 5):

You should use a regular expression to do that. See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Or, if it keeps that simple, you can check like this:

```
if( str.matches( "[ABC]+" ) ) {
    System.out.println("YES");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know of a concise library of regex syntax?

Comment: I'm always using the cited `Pattern`-javadoc.